# Transforming Text File into One Line

Tags: bash

I have a set of large text files. For example, [*War and Peace* from Project Gutenburg](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt). I need to make it so that the text fits into one (obviously very long) line in a text file, i.e. no line breaks. I am using bash on OS X.

So far I have tried several different commands to transform the file (pg2600.txt) into a new file (output.txt) to no avail.

`tr -d '\n' <pg2600.txt > output.txt` seemed promising but when I open it up in a text editor, the line breaks are still there.

The end goal is to transform something like this:

```
"Madame, I doubt my ability before such an audience," said he,
smilingly inclining his head.
```

into

```
"Madame, I doubt my ability before such an audience," said he, smilingly inclining his head.
```

Comment: Might the text file have `\r\n` line endings?  That looks correct to me.

Comment: Just as @squiguy also suggested, try `tr -d '\r\n' <pg2600.txt > output.txt`

Comment: @squiguy Woohoo! That works. Do you want to leave as an answer?

Comment: Hmm, I feel like that doesn't merit rep.  Just a simple mistake :).

Comment: @squiguy Well, much obliged. A mistake that cost me a good amount of time.. :)

Comment: I'll post it so you people will know you solved it.

Comment: does this work? `paste -d"\0" -s file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since text files may have an extra `\r`, UNIX operating systems may not recognize them.  So you could use this instead:

```
tr -d '\r' < input > output
```

Or in this case to remove all the newlines use:

```
tr -d '\r\n' < input > output
```